# WSO2 ESB integration SAP

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, jco

We are using WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus. We would like to know that we can do integration via SAP JCo library or SAP BAPIs published as web services by using WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus products? 
Thanks
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Look at ESB Dokumentaion: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/SAP+Integration 
and Configuration of the ESB Adapter: http://www.yenlo.nl/nl/configuring-wso2-sap-adapter/